# GetFeatureInfo is not working on multiple layer

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo, leaflet.wms

This is my map URL: http://34.84.56.42:8080/app/

When I click on the map, I'm able not to get the information (`GetFeatureInfo`) of the overlay layers. I can get only `GetFeatureInfo` of the top layer.

I just changed the WMS source and layers in the example code.

[image: 스크린샷 2020-11-10 오후 3 05 54]

In the example,
[image: 스크린샷 2020-11-10 오후 3 05 28]

When I click on the map, the information of the two overlapping layers appears.
How can I fix it?

---

```
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': './lib',
    'paths': {
        'leaflet.wms': '../src/leaflet.wms' //.js'
    }
});

define(['leaflet', 'leaflet.wms'],
function(L, wms) {

var tiledMap = createMap('tiled-map', true);

function createMap(div, tiled) {
    // Map configuration
    var map = L.map(div);
    map.setView([37.568,126.993035], 17);

    // 베이스맵 설정
    var basemaps = {
        'OpenStreetMap': basemap().addTo(map),
        'Blank': blank()
    };


    // Add WMS source/layers
    var source = wms.source(
        "http://34.84.56.42:8080/geoserver/yh_test/wms",
        {
            "format": "image/png",
            "transparent": "true",
            "attribution": "<a href='https://betacity.center/'>BetaCityCenter</a>",
            "info_format": "text/html",
            "tiled": tiled,
        }        
    );

    // 레이어 설정
    var layers = {
        'yh_test:200814_JungGu_JongroGu_Buld(epsg5186)': source.getLayer("200814_JungGu_JongroGu_Buld(epsg5186)").addTo(map),
        'yh_test:200702_Japaneese house_GUGA': source.getLayer("200702_Japaneese house_GUGA").addTo(map),
        'yh_test:200702_Korean house_GUGA': source.getLayer("200702_Korean house_GUGA").addTo(map),
        'yh_test:guga_yh': source.getLayer("guga_yh").addTo(map),
        'yh_test:Sewoon_area(epsg5186)': source.getLayer("Sewoon_area(epsg5186)").addTo(map),
        'yh_test:3D_scan_UOS_process': source.getLayer("3D_scan_UOS_process").addTo(map),
        'yh_test:Process_area': source.getLayer("Process_area").addTo(map),
    };

    // 레이어 선택창 생성
    L.control.layers(basemaps, layers).addTo(map);
}

// 오픈스트리트맵으로 베이스맵을 설정
function basemap() {
    var attr = '<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    return L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution: attr
    });
}

// 베이스맵 없는 상태
function blank() {
    var layer = new L.Layer();
    layer.onAdd = layer.onRemove = function() {};
    return layer;
}
});
```

Comment: What about having a look at the source code of the working example?

Comment: What actual GetFeatureInfo requests are sent? do you list all layers you want to query in the `query_layers`, and `layers` parameters? How many features are you requesting in the `feature_count`, and are there always features where you click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have omitted a feature_count parameter.

So looking at a WMS 1.1.1 GetMap request like

[image: GetMap request]

Your application is sending a GetFeatureInfo request like:

> http://34.84.56.42:8080/geoserver/yh_test/wms?service=WMS&request=GetFeatureInfo&version=1.1.1&layers=200814_JungGu_JongroGu_Buld(epsg5186)%2C200702_Japaneese%20house_GUGA%2C200702_Korean%20house_GUGA%2Cguga_yh%2CSewoon_area(epsg5186)%2C3D_scan_UOS_process%2CProcess_area&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=TRUE&info_format=text%2Fhtml&tiled=true&width=1880&height=970&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=14136279.537331868%2C4518190.353279633%2C14137402.206184806%2C4518769.602634608&query_layers=200814_JungGu_JongroGu_Buld(epsg5186)%2C200702_Japaneese%20house_GUGA%2C200702_Korean%20house_GUGA%2Cguga_yh%2CSewoon_area(epsg5186)%2C3D_scan_UOS_process%2CProcess_area&X=1106&Y=473&

Which returns one feature (for layer `200814_JungGu_JongroGu_Buld(epsg5186)`.

What you need is to add a `feature_count` parameter like:

> http://34.84.56.42:8080/geoserver/yh_test/wms?service=WMS&request=GetFeatureInfo&version=1.1.1&layers=200814_JungGu_JongroGu_Buld(epsg5186)%2C200702_Japaneese%20house_GUGA%2C200702_Korean%20house_GUGA%2Cguga_yh%2CSewoon_area(epsg5186)%2C3D_scan_UOS_process%2CProcess_area&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=TRUE&info_format=text%2Fhtml&tiled=true&width=1880&height=970&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=14136279.537331868%2C4518190.353279633%2C14137402.206184806%2C4518769.602634608&query_layers=200814_JungGu_JongroGu_Buld(epsg5186)%2C200702_Japaneese%20house_GUGA%2C200702_Korean%20house_GUGA%2Cguga_yh%2CSewoon_area(epsg5186)%2C3D_scan_UOS_process%2CProcess_area&X=1106&Y=473&feature_count=100&

Which in this example returns two features (one from `200814_JungGu_JongroGu_Buld(epsg5186)` and the other from `Sewoon_area(epsg5186)`

If you use a WMS 1.3.0 request, as opposed to 1.1.1 (according to the specification) you don't need the `feature_count` parameter to return one feature from each query layer, but to be safe it's worth always adding it.